# Can it be launched from mail?

Tags: ios, email

I'm working on a new app and would love to have the following feature. If the user is in Apple's Mail, they can have the option to open my app.

EDIT: The comments have pointed me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application), which is perfect for handling attachments, which I also want to do, but I also want the user to be able to copy some text, a date or an e-mail address, and then open my app with that information in tow.

Is there an API set up whereby I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Comment: I'm not so interested in certain file types. I really want to know how to launch my app from Mail with certain information attached, and that info may be a file or a date or an e-mail address or a string of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom URL scheme for your app, something like app://path - this is how Facebook handles things, they have URLs like `fb://profile/12345`.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks! I've only skimmed the link, but to me it does not appear that I can use this to open my app from Mail. It seems instead that this creates a way for me (or others) to open my app from within another application. Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: If your app is sending e-mail notifications, you can include a link using the custom scheme to pass data to the app if the user clicks. You can't extend the default Mail.app copy/paste/select functionality, though - apps cannot add plugins to other apps like that.