# How to Open an iPad/iPhone app through a mail link?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, plist

I have developed a universal iPhone/iPad app. I need to open this app through a mail file link(with some extension like .xyz) i,e when I click the link in mail(opened through safari or some other web servers) my app should launch and also the file contents must be loaded inside the app. What are all the settings I need to do in .plist file? And how to handle the file contents once loaded at launch?
Can anybody help me how to do this?

Any help will be greatly respected.
Thank

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can my app be launched from mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369892/can-my-app-be-launched-from-mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Implementing Support for Custom File Formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW12) is a great way to get started. Yes, you need to define the document types in your Info.plist and then when your app gets launched by opening this kind of files you get a dictionary in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: app delegate method with info about it, including the file path. How you handle the file after that depends on file type and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot fichek.. Could you please give some link which describes well enough the settings of URL schemes and doc types inside .plist?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify scheme in application **plist** file (you can find how specify scheme for example on "**step 6**" for [FBConnect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios))

Comment: You can use any name for the scheme you want like: `MyGreatApp:`

Comment: That's not what is being asked here. He wants to open a file from Mail (or other apps) in his app.

Comment: @fichek:When I click a link in my inbox which has file extension like.xyz my app should launch. So what all I need to do?

Comment: @rckoenes: Should I have to mention my file extension .xyz anywhere inside .plist??

Comment: Check the answer from `fichek` that is what you want.

Comment: Or if you want associate files with your application, than check response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application